# Python: generate all possible subsets of a dictionary of lists

Tags: python

I have a dictionary like this:

```
d = {
  “Samsung”: [“2.3”,”127”,”early”],
  “google”: [“pixel”,”15”],
  “IBM”: [“Z”,”7.13”,”main”,”VM”]
}
```

What I want is to generate is all possible unique subsets of each key and value so the output should look something like this:

```
{Samsung: “2.3”}
{Samsung: “2.3”, google: “pixel”}
{Samsung: “2.3”, google: “pixel”, IBM: “Z”}
{Samsung: “2.3”, google: “pixel”, IBM: “7.13”}
……
{Samsung: “127”}
{Samsung: “127”,google:”pixel”}
```

Etc and so on for each combination. The order doesn’t really matter as along as all values are represented. The closest questions I found that was somewhat related was [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/171173/list-all-possible-permutations-from-a-python-dictionary-of-lists) but that’s permutations of the entire dictionary so it doesn’t give
Me a values like {Samsung: “2.3”, google: “pixel”}

Comment: You can merge all the tuples into a list and then use the permutations function.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar would that preserve the keys tho? I would think that would just generate the values

Comment: I said tuples. A tuple in a dict is a key-value pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `itertools.product`:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> subsets = [{k: v for k, v in p if v} for p in product(*[[(k, i) for i in v + [None]] for k, v in d.items()])]
```

produces:

```
{'Samsung': '2.3', 'google': 'pixel', 'IBM': 'Z'}
{'Samsung': '2.3', 'google': 'pixel', 'IBM': '7.13'}
{'Samsung': '2.3', 'google': 'pixel', 'IBM': 'main'}
{'Samsung': '2.3', 'google': 'pixel', 'IBM': 'VM'}
{'Samsung': '2.3', 'google': 'pixel'}
{'Samsung': '2.3', 'google': '15', 'IBM': 'Z'}
{'Samsung': '2.3', 'google': '15', 'IBM': '7.13'}
{'Samsung': '2.3', 'google': '15', 'IBM': 'main'}
{'Samsung': '2.3', 'google': '15', 'IBM': 'VM'}
{'Samsung': '2.3', 'google': '15'}
{'Samsung': '2.3', 'IBM': 'Z'}
{'Samsung': '2.3', 'IBM': '7.13'}
{'Samsung': '2.3', 'IBM': 'main'}
{'Samsung': '2.3', 'IBM': 'VM'}
{'Samsung': '2.3'}
{'Samsung': '127', 'google': 'pixel', 'IBM': 'Z'}
```

etc.